# Dynamically generate multiple divs based on json data atttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, underscore.js

I'm trying to put the the fixtures in this data http://www.football-data.org//soccerseasons/354/fixtures into separate divs based on the matchday attribute. I have no idea how. I've used Underscore's groupBy but dont know how to dynamically put the data into separate divs generated by the remaining matchdays. Can anyone help?

```
 getRemainingFixtures = function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/fixtures/later_fixtures',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(data){
        data = _.groupBy(data,'matchday');
        console.log(data);

        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          $.each(value, function(index, game) {

            $('#fixtures').append('<p> <button style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 40px;">Down Score</button> ' +  game.homeTeam + ' <button style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 40px;">Up Score</button> V <button style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 40px;">Down Score</button> ' + game.awayTeam + ' <button style="width: 50px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: normal;height: 40px;">Up Score</button></p>');

            $('#fixtures').css({
              'max-width': '80%',
              'display': 'inline-block',
              'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
              'white-space': 'nowrap',
              'float': 'left',
              'border': 'black 1px solid'
            });
          })
        })
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the output of console.log(data)?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it! http://imgur.com/a/pEkbA

Comment: I would recommend you a standard while instead of jQuery each(3 times faster) https://jsperf.com/foreach-speed-test/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'http://jsbin.com/zinefu/1.json',
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data){
  data = _.groupBy(data,'matchday');
  $.each(data, function(index, day){
    var matchdatediv = $('<div>');
    var h1 = $('<h1>').html(day[0].matchday);
    matchdatediv.append(h1);
    $.each(day,function(index2, game){
      var div = $('<div>');
      var h4 = $('<h4>').html(game.homeTeam);
      div.append(h4);
      matchdatediv.append(div);
    });
    $('#fixtures').append(matchdatediv);
  });
});
```

I iterated through the data and created a sample of how to iterate through each game object.

The structure that you see in the demo is like this

```
<div>
  <h1>match date 1
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4>home team for game 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4>home team for game 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
....
</div>

<div>
  <h1>match date 2
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4>home team for game 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4>home team for game 5</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
....
</div>

........
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/pumasa/1/edit?html,js,output)
Hope this helps.

Comment: if you think it solved the question please mark it as answered so that others can benefit from it as well